# Help error states “ Please Unlock Disk nvmeOn1p3_crypt “

Tags: password, nvme, cryptsetup

I’m not the tech savvy girl here, I had this laptop given to me and it was working ok tell now, it updated today and now won’t let me log back in after restart, it’s prompting that “unlock disk nvmeOn1p3_crypt “
Is anyone able to help walk me though what I need to do? I have tried all my own passwords.
Thanks,
Amy

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you have to enter a password when you turned the laptop on?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a password prompt to decrypt the OS.  If you don't know the password, you need to ask the person who set it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do to open it if you forgot the password for the encryption. You have to wipe and reinstall the entire computer. That, of course, provided that you can do that given the settings in the BIOS (initial software) of the computer. You may be able to hit F12 and choose to boot off a usb drive or whatever. But, if someone is serious about the security it's likely they turned all of that off and have yet another password to turn it all back on.

Just posted here for future reference given that so much time has elapsed since you initially posted the question.